# How do I change a Cartopy contour plot into box plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartopy

I have plotted a CartoPy contour plot which looks like this:

[image]

using the following script:

```
precip_full1 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1979.nc')
precip_full2 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1980.nc')
precip_full3 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1981.nc')
precip_full4 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1982.nc')
precip_full5 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1983.nc')
precip_full6 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1984.nc')

precip_full = xr.concat([precip_full1,precip_full2,precip_full3,precip_full4,precip_full5,precip_full6],dim = 'time')


output = []

for x in np.arange(6.5,10.25,0.25):
    for y in np.arange(-15,-9.75,0.25):
        precip = precip_full.where((precip_full.latitude==x)&(precip_full.longitude==y),drop=True)
        roll = precip.rolling(time=6,center=False).sum()
    

        annual = roll.groupby('time.year').max()

        tab = annual.to_dataframe().rename(columns={'tp':6})

    


output = pd.concat(output,1)


mean = output.mean()


data_mean = pd.DataFrame(mean, columns=['mean'])

df = data_mean.to_numpy()

new = [df[i:i+21] for i in range(0,len(df),21)]

new = np.reshape(new, [-1, 21])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=new, dtype=object)


lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)


plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-15,-10,6.5,10])
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS) 


gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=np.arange(-180,180,0.25), ylocs=np.arange(-90,90,0.25),linewidth=0.4)
gl.top_labels   = False
gl.right_labels = False
plot = plt.contourf(lon2d, lat2d, df, cmap = 'jet', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I've now realized I'd prefer a box plot, with one solid colour in each grid box, I no longer want interpolation between grid points.

I found that I can use pcolormesh instead of contour to do this. However, when I change the last line of code:

```
plot = plt.pcolormesh(lon2d, lat2d, df, cmap = 'jet', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Dimensions of C (15, 21) are incompatible with X (15) and/or Y (15)
```

I can't see what this error means to know how to fix it. Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: its because pcolormesh expects as coordinates `The coordinates of the quadrilateral corners.` and not the datapoints ([check the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) )
I've implemented several possibilities to visualize 1D or 2D datasets as projected ellipses, rectangles etc. in [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)... (it uses cartopy under the hood so you can use all cartopy functionalities alongside EOmaps)

Comment: Okay, I'll try using that! How would I create a box plot using EO maps? Can't seem to find an example of a simple box plot

Comment: hey, if I understand correctly you want something like this: [simple ellipse plot](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/EOmaps_examples.html#quickly-visualize-your-data) but with rectangles right?  (a boxplot would actually be something like this: [mpl-boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html)

Answer (score 1):

OK, since you've asked... here's a quick example how you can do it with [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)...

Note that data and coordinates can be provided as 1D or 2D arrays (or mixtures of 1D and 2D as below) or as a `pandas.DataFrames`.
It's also possible to plot directly from a NetCDFs (or GeoTIFFs) via `m.new_layer_from_file.NetCDF(...)`

```py
from eomaps import Maps
import numpy as np

# create some data in a regular lon/lat grid (=epsg 4326)
x, dx = np.linspace(-45, 45, 55, retstep=True)
y, dy = np.linspace(-20, 30, 25, retstep=True)
vals = np.random.randint(0,100, (x.size, y.size))

# plot the data as lon/lat rectangles on a map displayed in Orthographic projection.
m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Orthographic())
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.set_data(vals, x, y, crs=4326)
m.set_shape.rectangles(radius=(dx/2, dy/2), radius_crs=4326)
m.plot_map()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble installing EO Maps? I'm using the Anaconda distribution, and I tried every method on the notes. Have you come across a similar problem?

Comment: hey, I don't have any problems installing EOmaps with conda... if you open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps/issues) and provide some details I can try to help! (I'd suggest the following: create a new environment, then first do `conda install -c conda-forge mamba` to speed up the process... and then `mamba install -c conda-forge eomaps` )