# Mapping a box contour. Are there any mapping alternatives to pcolor?

Tags: python, pandas, cartopy

I have created a map that interpolates values between gridpoints, using Cartopy 'contouf'

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a way I can change the map so that it doesn't interpolate, and so instead each grid square will be a solid color, like this (but not rotated around the pole):

[image]

From what I've researched, these are called block plots, which can be made using 'pcolormesh'. This is what I've tried:

```
precip_full1 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1979.nc')
precip_full2 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1980.nc')
precip_full3 = xr.open_dataset('era_yr1981.nc')

precip_full = xr.concat([precip_full1,precip_full2,precip_full3],dim='time')



output = []

for x in np.arange(6.5,10.25,0.25):
    for y in np.arange(-15,-9.75,0.25):
        precip = precip_full.where((precip_full.latitude==x)&(precip_full.longitude==y),drop=True)
        roll = precip.rolling(time=6,center=False).sum()
    

        annual = roll.groupby('time.year').max()

        tab = annual.to_dataframe().rename(columns={'tp':6})

   
        output.append(tab)
    


output = pd.concat(output,1)



mean = output.mean()


data_mean = pd.DataFrame(mean, columns=['mean'])

df = data_mean.to_numpy()

new = [df[i:i+21] for i in range(0,len(df),21)]


new = np.reshape(new, [-1, 21])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=new, dtype=object)

lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-15,-10,6.5,10])
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)


gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=np.arange(-180,180,0.25), ylocs=np.arange(-90,90,0.25),linewidth=0.4)
gl.top_labels   = False
gl.right_labels = False
plot = plt.pcolor(lon2d, lat2d, df, cmap = 'jet', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

For which I get the error:

```
TypeError: Dimensions of C (15, 21) are incompatible with X (15) and/or Y (15)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here, or is there an easier alternative?

Comment: Aside: please don't use `jet` as a colourmap. It's lightness is not uniform (try viewing or printing it in greyscale), and has long been abolished in the defaults of Matplotlib. Have a read through https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html for more information, and better colourmaps.

Comment: You mention `pcolormesh`, yet you use `plt.pcolor()` in your code.

Comment: The error message is fairly clear: you're passing a 15x21 map of colours, but X and Y are 15 by 15. So your map should be 15x15 as well. Besides, you're passing a DataFrame for some reason, which doesn't make sense: it should just be a NumPy 2D array (admittedly, a dataframe is like that, but it has a totally different function. Don't use dataframes where 2D arrays should be used).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change a Cartopy contour plot into box plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680414/how-do-i-change-a-cartopy-contour-plot-into-box-plot)